# Cannot retrieve Trigger using Interactions method

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I've tried tried using the [Interactions method](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/interaction/getInteractionCollection.html) to retreive (GET) all Interactions. This works fine, however the `triggers` array is empty for each Interaction object:

```
{
    "id":"2a6454c4-4e6d-4362-9f33-085ef407d0b3",
    "key":"549d8108-b8b7-8c21-6eff-921f61db164d",
    "name":"Gold Member Rewards",
    "lastPublishedDate":"2015-03-24T15:47:04",
    "description":"",
    "version":1,
    "workflowApiVersion":1,
    "createdDate":"2015-03-23T12:48:07.573",
    "modifiedDate":"2015-03-24T15:47:04.04",
    "triggers":[],
    "goals":[],
    etc...
}
```

If I use the method to [get an Interaction by Id](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/interaction/getInteractionById.html) (that is, I retrieve a single Interaction) then the Trigger is returned in the response payload.

According to the documentation to [retrieve Interactions](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/interaction/getInteractionCollection.html), the response should contain a Triggers object (as it includes an example with a trigger in the response). But it doesn't behave like this. Is this a bug or has this support been removed?

It's possible to recursively get the trigger for each Interaction, but this requires a lot of API requests to achieve something that should work in a single request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the "extras=all" query param, you'll get the triggers:

```
GET https://jbinteractions.exacttargetapps.com/fuelapi/interaction/v1/interactions/?id=[guid]&mostRecentVersionOnly=true&extras=all
```