# Copy journeys between business units?

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, api, journeybuilder

does anyone know a way to quickly copy journeys from Journey Builder from one business unit to another one?

It would be a huge time saver when we're setting up new journeys on separate business units that follow the same logic and have a complicated structure. I imagine it would be possible either via API or with some external tools that utilize the API to perform the action.

I've managed to read the json structure of a specific journey with the following API calls:

- `GET /interaction/v1/interactions` (to get the list of journeys on a MID and the ID of the journey that I want to retrieve)
- `GET /interaction/v1/interactions/{id}` (to retrieve the chosen journey)

Is it somehow possible to use the returned JSON to create a clone in a different business unit? I imagine that it might not be immediately possible to copy and publish immediately, but even being able to copy as a draft on another business unit would be helpful and less prone to human error.

Has anyone done something similar in the past to streamline their work?

Comment: I'm guessing no, but don't let that deter you from giving it a shot.  Journey templates are just around the corner, so it may lessen the need to do what you're talking about.

Comment: Hi, Adam,
thanks for the answer. Journey templates could indeed be helpful. 

It might be a fun project to test the API and coding skills and I might attempt to develop something like this in the future.

Comment: Hey @rafal were you able to achieve this ? We are currently facing the same situation where we need to clone journeys to different BU's.

Comment: Hey @Vic, I sadly had to abandon the search due to time constraints. I can say I managed to clone a journey without the entry event within a business unit (should be possible to post it a different BU as well). 

You need to do the following: get the token, retrieve all journeys from a given BU, find the journey you want cloned and retrieve the Journey ID, get the Journey based on the ID, insert the journey where you want it.

Comment: @Vic,
I just noticed that you should be able to retrieve the entry event as well (and possibly insert it into a clone): https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/71132/cannot-retrieve-trigger-using-interactions-method?

This might lead you to a proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a [Salesforce Labs app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FvMviUAF) that can now accomplish copying the canvas from one BU to another